# How many 7-digit telephone numbers have an odd number of even numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

((7 choose 1)*5^7) + (7 choose 3)*5^7) + (7 choose 3)*5^7) + (7 choose 1)*5^7)

This is how I attempted to solve the problem, but I'm not sure if its correct.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by a number having "an odd number of even numbers". Do you mean, "an odd number of even **digits**"??

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all $7$-digit numbers are admissible, including those with leading zeroes, note that

$$N \mapsto 9999999 - N$$

is a bijection from the set of $7$-digit numbers to itself with the property that it interchanges even digits with odd. So, it maps a number with $n$ even digits to a number with $7 - n$ even digits, and thus a number with an odd number of even digits to one with an even number.

This gives a bijection between the $7$-digits numbers with an odd number of even digits and those with an even number, so the counts of those two types are the same. Since there are $10^7$ $7$-digit numbers, there are
$$\tfrac{1}{2} \cdot 10^7 = 5 \cdot 10^6$$
$7$-digits numbers with an odd number of even digits.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that all strings of $7$ digits are allowed.

Take **any** string of $6$ digits. If it has an odd number of even digits, it can be completed to a number with an odd number of even digits by appending any of the $5$ odd digits.

If it has an even number of even digits, it can be completed to a number with an odd number of even digits by appending any of the $5$ even digits.

So any of the $10^6$ $6$-digit strings can be completed in $5$ ways to a $7$-digit string with an odd number of even digits.

It follows that the total number is $5\times 10^6$.

**Remark:** I prefer to say that half of all the $10^7$ possible $7$-digit telephone numbers qualify.

Let us suppose that there are restrictions on the kind of telephone numbers available, but that for any allowed $6$-digit initial string can be completed to a legitimate telephone number in $10$ ways. Then our argument goes through with essentially no change, and we find that if there are $N$ legal telephone numbers, then $\frac{N}{2}$ of them have an odd number of even digits.